# Pass parameter to Twilio client

Tags: java, twilio

I have a Java application, which will call to the Twilio Softphone application, which is running on a different server.

My question is: how can I pass custom parameters from my application to the Twilio Softphone application?

Edit 1 :

When I got a request from server to call so my application call two parallel number means one call to Customer and another call to Customer Care which is Twilio Softphone. In customer care application Twilio Taskrouter is used.
So when my application called to Twilio Sofphone I need to send some parameter like Customer Number, Lat, Long etc. I have tried to send it by using Twilio app url but no success.

Comment: I have reworded your question, but I'm afraid it is still very broad. You can improve it by showing what you've tried and how it didn't work for you.

Comment: Please see edited question

Comment: Even better would be actual code, I think.

Comment: Have to agree, not quite sure what you're doing here but would love to help. Do you have some code or more explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Is twilio provide any facility to send custom parameter because I have tried like adding parameter to URL e.g url?cust_no=123 but still I am confused, because this url is nothing but the URL which is used one of the twilio parameter while making a outbound call to any number from twilio so I want to send Param while making outbound call to Twilio Client.

Comment: down vote
The ability to answer an incoming call using the javascript client and respond to a piece of data in the app is essential. the best place to put this would be in the params that are passed with the incoming call

Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
 console.log('Incoming connection from ' + conn.parameters.From);
 console.log('My magic key passed with the call ' + conn.parameters.MyMagicCustomParam);
 // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
 conn.accept();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Megan from the [Twilio team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/132/twilio-developer-network).

Although it is possible to [send custom parameters from the Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect) to Twilio using our API, it is not possible to send them the other way.

You would need to figure out another way of sending custom parameters to Client, e.g. a separate AJAX request or WebSocket connection.